# Ant script gets killed but not with -verbose

Tags: java, ant, build-process, build-automation

I am running an ant script using `ant -f build.xml`. This script is supposed to compile my project and generate a jar file but some seconds after ant starts to generate the jar file, the project gets killed and all I see is the message "Killed" in the console.

If I run the same command but with the "-verbose" option, the build finishes successfully.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Update**:
This is the ant output i get:

```
Buildfile: build.xml

compile:

jar:
  [jar] Building jar: /var/lib/hudson/jobs/asproj/workspace/build/asproj.jar
Killed
```

This is the dmesg output I get after the process is killed:

```
Out of memory: kill process 16398 (bash) score 13929 or a child
Killed process 1499 (java)
```

So it's probably memory related, but it's not the ant jvm.. it has something to do with the bash process.

Comment: Are you running any JUnit tests too? It might be worth showing us the output from `ant`.

Comment: I updated my question with the ant ouput. I am not running any JUnit tests. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing JVM size using ANT_OPTS -

```
set ANT_OPTS=-Xms500m
```

This sets JVM size to 500 MB.